# 2 x 4:1 Switch or Demultiplexer

Tags: switches

I have 8 LED's and I am trying to turn 2 on at a time.  My voltage source is 5V and the LED's require up to 200 mA current.  I am finding quite a few demultiplex chips that are 2x4:1 but most of them do not operate in this range of voltage and current.  Does anyone have a suggestion for a higher current Demultiplex chip or a switch.  The reason demultiplex is appealing is because it has control inputs, which I need something similar to control the switch itself.  A chip I found that would be ideal, if the voltage and current maximums were larger, is the [TS3A5017](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scds188d/scds188d.pdf)

These LED's are BJT driven, which I won't go in to, but in order to turn them OFF the voltage source has to be off.

Comment: If the LEDs are BJT driven, then why does the switch/demux need to handle the high current? Wouldn't you be using the outputs to drive the BJTs, not the LEDs themselves? Aside from that, what "control inputs" do you plan to use? You could have 4 in use: Data, Select 0, Select 1, and enable, but it would only take four control lines to directly drive the four pairs of LEDs... Additionally, what will be controlling the switch/demux or the LEDs - manual switches, a computer, or a microcontroller?

Comment: So the LEDs are in the collector path, and so is the mux to disable current flow through the LED, therefore if the LED needs 200mA current to be maximum output, then the mux needs to be able to handle the same current. Although with that said it might be simpler to put the mux in the base path to reduce the current requirement....

Comment: Actually that would would required that I have 8 LED drivers instead of 2, so nevermind

Comment: One BJT can easily drive 2 LEDs... Similarly, one control line could easily drive two BJTs. I'm confused with your reasoning...

Comment: On top of that, the BJT itself is what should be enabling current through the LED. Putting something else in the path is redundant and only introduces a point of failure. Hence, you should control the current flow by way of the BJT base. What you suggest will require control of the demux/switch as well as the BJT base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with using extremely high frequencies to switch LEDs: The LED junction capacitance becomes a factor, and intensity drops significantly as the LED does not get the required excitation time per pulse.

LEDs have a minimum rise time specified, refer to the datasheet of the LED concerned to determine yours.

In other words, the light will be dimmer than at lower frequencies, and PWM dimming will be much less linear than with lower frequencies.

---

Assuming that the frequency for controlling the LED can be dropped much lower, an alternative approach is to use a high current rated latching serial-in-parallel-out power shift register like the [Texas Instruments TPIC6A595](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6a595.pdf).

This shift register has a high enough current rating, 350 mA per channel, to be able to sink the 200 mA per LED load described. What it lacks is the speed to handle the 120/125 MHz signal rates mentioned in one of OP's comments.

The benefit of this approach is that it requires a small number of control pins from your controller, and since the device is cascadeable, increasing the LED count does not increase required pin count.

If an even higher current drive is required, it is simple to drive two MOSFET arrays like the [Hitachi 4AK21](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/HitachiSemiconductor/mXrzswt.pdf) from each shift register. This array is rated at 8 Amperes per channel (so long as per-channel dissipation is under 4 watts across  R<sub>ds<sub>on</sub></sub>=0.12 Ohms).

Answer (score 1):

Use an analogue switch. Maxim produce low-ohm on-resistance switches that are capable of switching 200mA from 5V. MAX14778 springs to mind.... http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/7406

Comment: ... only $10.70 each!

Comment: @vicatcu - cheapskate LOL. The point is that there ARE devices available BUT if the price is high then it means the application is more obscure so the OP can consider alternative methods such as using individual FETs or BJTs. Nevertheless it is an excellent device.

Comment: Just ran into a problem,  I failed to mention that my signal frequency is at 120 MHz and 125 MHz.  So I think this component may be too lossy and has too much crosstalk

Comment: Is that frequency to pulse the LEDs? That would be ridiculously high. Maybe you should tell us what sort of LED driver you are using.

Comment: @mkitchen You might discover that pulsing LEDs at MHz rates does not deliver the control desired: At those frequencies the junction capacitance and light emission behavior of LEDs begin to play a significant role.